# Need help creating an extra access point with second router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I recently upgraded my internet to 40mb/s.
This meant I had to get a new modem (I had an adsl2 modem before that), and where I live you can only get them from your Infrastructure provider. I got a new modem+router model D-LINK 6850U. Turns out it has pretty horrible range, so I figured I could use my old router (which is also an adsl2 modem model: Siemens Gigaset 604 IL) into an extra access point. I have an Ethernet cable connected through the wall into a desktop PC, and it would be fine connecting the AP next to the desktop. Because these are weird models, I have no idea how to tinker with the router to turn it into an AP.
Also, the new modem+router (the one I currently use)has a default gateway of 10.0.0.138, and the old one has a default gateway of 192.168.1.1, how do I make them work together?
Here are some screenshots I took from the old router(the one I want to turn into an AP):
http://imgur.com/a/dhscd
My knowledge in networking is next to nothing, so please ask for additional screenshots if they are needed.
Thanks!
Edit: Solved. My router didn't have the option to disable DHCP in an easy-to-find place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your old router has LAN ports, they are bridged with the WLAN. So all that you need to do is to shut down the DHCP server on the old router, and connect its LAN port to a LAN port of the new router. You connect to the old router with its own WLAN SSID and password, but will get IP address and internet access from the DHCP server and Default Gateway of your new router.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find the "Disable DHCP" option anywhere. Under which category should it be? I don't mind adding extra screenshots. Also, I heard I needed to change the IPs range on one of the routers, and I have no idea how to do that either.

Comment: DHCP server is usually configured in LAN settings.